# Count/group rows based on date including missing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of rows in my db that signify orders, i.e.

```
id | date
---------------------
1  | 2013-09-01
2  | 2013-09-01
3  | 2013-09-02
4  | 2013-09-04
5  | 2013-09-04
```

What I'd like is to display the count of rows per day, including missing days, so the output would be:

```
2013-09-01 | 2
2013-09-02 | 1
2013-09-03 | 0
2013-09-04 | 2
```

I've seen examples of having 2 tables, one with the records and the other with dates, but I'd ideally like to have a single table for this.

I can currently find the rows that have a record, but not days that do not.

Does anyone have a n idea on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If your date range is not limited somehow, the only good option is to have two tables (one with dates) since MySQL does not support sequences.

Comment: It will be limited to display the orders in the last 7 days preferably.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078798/selecting-missing-rows-and-grouping-by-date-with-read-only-access-to-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data for last 7 days, you can generate your pseudo-table via `UNION`, like:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(t.id), 
  fixed_days.fixed_date 
FROM t 
  RIGHT JOIN 
  (SELECT CURDATE() as fixed_date 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 day) AS fixed_days 
  ON t.`date` = `fixed_days`.`fixed_date`
GROUP BY 
  `fixed_days`.`fixed_date`
```

-see this [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/be53d/2). Note, that if your fields are `DATETIME` date type, then you'll need to applyy `DATE()` first:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(t.id), 
  fixed_days.fixed_date 
FROM t 
  RIGHT JOIN 
  (SELECT CURDATE() as fixed_date 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 day 
   UNION ALL SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 day) AS fixed_days 
  ON DATE(t.`date`) = `fixed_days`.`fixed_date`
GROUP BY 
  `fixed_days`.`fixed_date`
```

Comment: That returns `1` for each row regardless if there is no rows in the date range

Comment: What if the fields were `datetime`? Is it easy to change your SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this!

```
SELECT 
  c1,  
  GROUP_CONCAT(c2 ORDER BY c2) AS 'C2 values' 
FROM table 
GROUP BY c1;
```

To retrieve a list of c1 values for which there exist specific values in another column c2, you need an `IN` clause specifying the c2 values and a `HAVING` clause specifying the required number of different items in the list ...

```
SELECT c1  
FROM table 
WHERE c2 IN (1,2,3,4) 
GROUP BY c1 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c2)=4;
```

For more help by this related question

[Counting all rows with specific columns and grouping by week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036294/counting-all-rows-with-specific-columns-and-grouping-by-week)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following stored procedure it will allow you to get results for more than 7 days, just pass the number of days you want

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`server`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(d INT)
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dates 
    (
      f_day DATETIME
    );

    WHILE d > 0 DO
        INSERT INTO dates SELECT DATE(NOW())-d;
        SET d = d - 1;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT 
        IF(isnull(`id`),0,`id`), 
        `fixed_days`.`f_day`
    FROM t 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        dates AS `fixed_days` 
        ON t.`date` = `fixed_days`.`f_day`
    GROUP BY 
    `fixed_days`.`f_day`;

    DROP TABLE dates;
END
```